# Change between drives in filezilla client

Tags: mount, ftp, drive-letters

I have Filezilla server running on a Windows 7 machine with a few users created. Right now I am forced to create a separate user for each of my three drives on that machine (C:, E:, and F:) because I cannot figure out how to change between drives while using filezilla client. I can traverse directories normally but I can only get to the drive that is set as "Home Directory" in the user settings on the server. How can I change drives without changing user?

I suppose mounting E: and F: as directories on C: like C:\E_Drive and C:\F_Drive would work but I don't want to do that unless I can keep them mounted as drive letters as well. Any suggestions?

I wasn't sure if this is a serverfault or a superuser question but because the solution could be a client or a server fix, I posted it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never run Filezilla Server, so I don't know if it has any built-in ways to deal with this.  But assuming it can deal with NTFS junctions, that's a fairly easy workaround.  Basically open a command prompt in the home directory or wherever you want the mount points to be and use the following command:

```
mklink /j E_Drive e:\
mklink /j F_Drive f:\
```

Comment: interesting link on this subject: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html  .  Also, I prefer WinSSHD as a FTP server and Tunnelier as a client.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. That worked excellently. No upvote though because I'm <15 :(